# send traffic from openvpn to IPIP tunnel

Tags: tunnel

We have a network interface that is open to the Internet. (ens160) We created an ipip tunnel and it was established correctly as expected (we placed 10.10.30.1 <-->10.10.30.2 | mytun) then we tried to create an OpenVPN interface to allow remote users access to this ipip tunnel and grant access to 10.10.30.1 server. (OpenVPN was properly setup on 10.10.30.2 server)

Now I need to pass traffic of OpenVPN users (10.18.0.0/24) to the ipip tunnel. I tried to forward / masq but I couldn't get it to work.

I need to route all traffic of OpenVPN users to this tunnel and just OpenVPN users, not any others.

Comment: What is end point (destinaton) of the traffic? Where should it eventually reach? Also [this recent question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1112260/routing-openvpn-traffic-to-ip-tunnel) looks very much like yours, probably you need just to use answer given there?

Comment: Thanks for comment . end point was  IPIP tunnel left hand ( 10.10.30.1)

Comment: Does it have a route to 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.10.30.2?